# App crashing when converting high resolution images into base64 in ionic

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to convert an image into base64 string , size of the image is around 5 to 7 MB. Converting this image into base64 takes too much time and on some devices the app will crash.

Comment: Please explain why you are converting the image into base64 and if / what alternative solutions may be acceptable. This yould be done by giving mroe information about the context.

Comment: Thank for your quick response. I am uploading images onto firebase via image URL. So what I am doing ,I am converting those URL's into base64 string and upload them to firebase storage.